# Which USB classes are supported driver-free?

Tags: windows, linux, usb, device-driver

Which USB classes are supported by a standard installation of Windows/Linux/etc, without product-specific drivers?

For example, a mass storage device is always supported, no matter what its VID/PID combination. What other classes work like this?

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser.com - please move it there.

Comment: Default support availability is most definitely a valid *programming* question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is all that programming related, but human interface devices are *generally* pretty well supported. There are of course still some HIDs which require "special" drivers for their extra features (drawing tablets, I'm looking at you).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, the answer to the title is really "none". All devices would require a driver, but some have in-box drivers. The more detailed question is answered by [USB FAQ : class drivers @ Microsoft WHDC](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/connect/usb/USBFAQ_intro.mspx#EBEAC)

Comment: I think the page you linked to has changed such that it doesn't include that content anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With HID you can basically write a translation driver in userspace if it's some unusual device that requires machine state to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 also has support for MTP over USB (which is an extension to the PTP class)